# assigning a key name from an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, set, key-value

I can't seem to make the key equal to the name of the index value of the array of names being passed in.

**What Im trying to do:**

create a key value of names and numbers to keep track of how many duplicate names I have.

**input/output:**

names = [bob, joe, jill, bob, bill, bill]

the output would be {bob:2, joe:1, jill:1, bill:2}

I haven't gotten to this part of the code yet. currently just trying to get the keys right. But it should paint a picture of what I'm trying to do.

**the Issue I'm having:**

I cant seem to create keys for each name in my set

**what I did initially:**

`myset.add({names[i]:0})`

which I changed to a variable called `keyname` that is being assigned right under my forloop.

this changed nothing.

---

```
function solution(names) {
    const myset = new Set();
    for(let i=0; i<names.length; i++){
        let keyname = names[i];
        if(myset.has(names[i])){
            console.log("already includes");
        }
        else(
            myset.add({
                keyname:0
            })
        )
    }
    console.log(myset);
}
```

---

**Console:**

```
Set(5) {
  { keyname: 0 },
  { keyname: 0 },
  { keyname: 0 },
  { keyname: 0 },
  { keyname: 0 }
}
```

Comment: what is the input array and what output you are expecting? Please add in the question itself

Comment: if my input is [bob,joe,jill, bob] my output would be bob:2, jill:1,joe:1. but I havent gotten to that part yet. Im just trying to create the set with the correct names right now

Comment: Please add the input and output that you are expecting in the quesiton itself... That would be much easier to understand for other people too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is just collection of unique values. If you are adding an object then It won't be equal to any other object unless both are not referentially same.

> Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the
> elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only
> occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection.

If you just have to count the occurrences of string then you can do this either using plain object or Map as:

```js
function solution(names) {
  const dict = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    if (!dict[names[i]]) dict[names[i]] = 1;
    else ++dict[names[i]];
  }

  console.log(dict);
}

solution(["bob", "joe", "jill", "bob"]);
```

```js
function solution(names) {
  const map = new Map();
  names.forEach((name) =>
    !map.has(name) ? map.set(name, 1) : map.set(name, map.get(name) + 1)
  );
  console.log(map);
}

solution(["bob", "joe", "jill", "bob"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an Object in Javascript. It can store key/value pairs.

```
function solution(names) {
    // javascript object
    const values = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        if(values[names[i]]){             
           values[names[i]] = 1;
        }else{
           values[names[i]] += 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(values);
}
```